# How to get a variable from the smart contract with web3 and abi?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, abi

I use web3.js and try to take a value of the variable from the smart contract.

My code for it is:

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);
```

where abi - json array and address - valid working address.

Part of abi json object is

```
{
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "weiRaised",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
},
```

When I use this code:

```
console.log(contract.abi[0].abi[6].name);
```

I see "weiRaised" in the console.

But if I use

```
console.log(contract.abi[0].abi[6].inputs);
```

I see 'undefined'.

What I am doing wrong?
How Can I get the variable from the smart contract, based on abi and web3.js?

Answer (score 5):

After printing stuff on the console, God let me go to sleep with joy =)

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);
async function getContractPublicVariable() {
    const weiRaised = await contract.methods.weiRaised.call().call();
}
```

so the idea is `contract.methods.VARIABLENAME.call().call();`

Comment: Another idea is `contract.methods.VARIABLENAME().call();`

Answer (score 1):

Web3.js will automagically map the ABI functions onto the contract object that you get back from `web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address)`.

This means you can access the value of the variables by doing something like:

`let weiRaisedValue = contract.weiRaised.call()`

Comment: console.log(contract.weiRaised.call()); - TypeError: contract.weiRaised is undefined

Comment: @Sergei Are you using web3 v1.0? In that case it should be `contract.methods.weiRaised.call().then(function (res) { console.log(res); })`. More info from web3 v1.0 [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call).

Comment: console.log(web3.version); gives this:  Object { api: "0.20.2", node: Getter, getNode: e(), network: Getter, getNetwork: e(), ethereum: Getter, getEthereum: e(), whisper: Getter, getWhisper: e() }

Comment: your code gives this error to me: TypeError: contract.methods is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an updated answer as of web3.js 1.6.0
(I used moralis as my provider for web3.js)

```
import Web3 from 'web3';       
const web3Js = new Web3(Moralis.provider);
            var contract = new web3Js.eth.Contract(ContractJSON.abi, ContractAddress);
            const variable = await contract.methods.variableName.call().call();
```

Comment: The double `call()` looks odd, it looks better with `contract.methods.variableName().call()`, using `()` after the name and a single `.call()`.

Answer (score 0):

### 2022 WebJs 1.7.3

If anyone struggle with it in 2022, then this is the solution

```js
import Web3 from "web3";

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      jsonInterface,
      address,
    );
this.age = await myContract.methods.getAge().call();
```

This is the generic form. And It is an async call
`await myContract.methods.getVariableName().call();`